# Apache LockFile issue

Tags: linux, apache

I am trying to migrate from Apache 2.2 on Debian 7 to Apache 2.4 on CentOS 7.
when httpd starts, it fails to start as below.

```
root# journalctl -xe
Jun 23 14:26:04 ww-test httpd[17716]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 47 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
Jun 23 14:26:04 ww-test httpd[17716]: Invalid command 'LockFile', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Jun 23 14:26:04 ww-test systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 23 14:26:04 ww-test kill[17718]: kill: cannot find process ""
Jun 23 14:26:04 ww-test systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 23 14:26:04 ww-test systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

```
vi httpd.conf
45 # The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
46 #
47 LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock
48
```

I installed the related package as below although I am not sure if it is the right one.

```
============================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                   Arch                              Version                                   Repository                                                      Size
============================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 lockfile-progs                            x86_64                            0.1.15-7.el7                              /lockfile-progs-0.1.15-7.el7.x86_64                             50 k
Installing for dependencies:
 liblockfile                               x86_64                            1.08-17.el7                               base                                                            21 k

Transaction Summary
```

Thanks for reading it.

Comment: `LockFile` is mentioned explicitly in the [migration guide](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#config).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock
```

To:

```
Mutex file:/var/httpd/locks default
```

Directives AcceptMutex, LockFile, RewriteLock, SSLMutex, SSLStaplingMutex, and WatchdogMutexPath have been replaced with a single Mutex directive. You will need to evaluate any use of these removed directives in your 2.2 configuration to determine if they can just be deleted or will need to be replaced using Mutex

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I have added just like you said. However, an error occurred as follows:  Jun 23 15:36:18 ww-test httpd[21984]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 48 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
Jun 23 15:36:18 ww-test httpd[21984]: Invalid Mutex directory in argument file:/var/lock/httpd$SUFFIX

Comment: could you use `Mutex file:/var/httpd/locks default` line and test.

Comment: After /var/httpd/locks directory creation, there is no error and httpd starts well.